# Whitelist Mobile data IP address on EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have whitelisted my mobile data IP address in the Load Balancer Security Group and I can access my application. But my mobile data IP address keeps changing when I am travelling. And I can not keep whitelisting my new IP addresses every time to access the mobile application running backend server on EC2.

So, how this situation can be tackled ?

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion to can tackle this  - The service that your mobile app is using open it for public IP (instead of restricting it mobile device app) and have some kind of authentication in your service using which only your mobile app can access.

For example - Send some userid/pwd in our service call which only your mobile device knows, validate the userid and password at server-side and hence no one else can access the service.

Comment: We have common backend server for mobile and web which is running on EC2 instance. And IP whitelisting works fine when we have office router network address allowed in the security group but for mobile data IP, it does not work due to dynamic IP.